# What is the correct way to convert the absolute path of the executing script to a URL, in WordPress?

Tags: urls, paths

In a nutshell, my question is "How do I convert the absolute path of the executing script, e.g.,

```
/home/content/xx/xxxxxxxx/html/wp-content/plugins/MY_PLUGIN_DIR/MY_PLUGIN/MY_PLUGIN.PHP
```

or

```
/home/content/xx/xxxxxxxx/html/wp-content/themes/MY_THEME/functions.php
```

to the absolute URL?"

```
http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/MY_PLUGIN_DIR/MY_PLUGIN.PHP
```

or

```
http://example.com/wp-content/themes/MY_THEME/functions.php
```

I don't even need the actual script name, just the path up to directory it's in.

#### Background

I've created a class that greatly simplifies creating an option page for a plugin. It doesn't (yet) do the heavy-lifting of registering/adding options via the Settings API, it's more a helper class that

- creates the menu item (add_menu_page or add_submenu_page)
- creates a plugin action link in the plugins listing page (plugin.php)
- displays a custom icon in the menu (if a top-level menu item)
- injects stylesheets and/or javascript files in the head - the WP way (register/enqueue)
- a few other misc. things related to creating an option page

It does these things with a minimal number of options passed in the instantiation of the class.

#### Problem

I created this class with only plugins in mind, but realized it works out of the box for themes, too...except in regards to generating URLs from relative references. Right now, I use

```
$my_url = plugins_url('/', __FILE__)
```

to generate URLs for stylesheets, script files (.js), and the menu icon file that are associated with the option page *only* if the user enters a relative URL. If they enter an absolute URL, I don't touch it. Example: if you include `'icon_url' => 'images/my-icon.png'` as an option, the class would convert that to

```
http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/MY_PLUGIN_DIR/MY_PLUGIN/images/my-icon.png
```

But since I've decided to make this class work for themes as well, I've realized I can't use `plugins_url`. I'm trying to stay away (if possible) from forcing the user to specify whether this class is going to be used for a plugin or a theme.

Is there a WordPress way similar to `plugins_url()` that I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) for the current theme, or [get_template_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) for the parent theme of a child theme, and append your file paths to that.

```
$url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/my-icon.png';
$url = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/my-icon.png';
```

Edit: To determine whether you're in a plugin, a parent theme or a child theme, compare the folder you're in (via `dirname(__FILE__)`) to [plugin_dir_path()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path), [get_template_directory()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) and [get_stylesheet_directory()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory) respectively.

Comment: Thanks, webaware, but that would require me to have the user specify that this was a theme instead of a plugin, something I'm trying to figure out programmatically. I'm trying to find a WordPress-centric way to get the URL from the absolute path if it's possible.

Comment: I can't see how you'd handle that, other than perhaps comparing `dirname(__FILE__)` to `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` (for plugins).

Comment: After more research, it's looking more and more like I'll have to take that route (comparing `__FILE__` to the plugin & theme directories). I plan on leaving this question open for 24 hours unless a slam-dunk answer comes along (doubtful). You should put your suggestion as an answer and I'll choose it, if no better answers come along.

Answer (score 0):

In your `wp-config.php` file, at the very end it should define `ABSPATH` to be the wp root folder.  You can then replace that from your filepath with `site_url` (or, if you've instead checked the path for theme/plugin/upload directory, then the appropriate url-function listed at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url#Related)